# How to use same enum in multiple files in Typescript without import

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, electron

I've been struggling with this now longer than I should and surprisingly, the existing questions (and there are many) don't really help further.

My goal is to declare and define `enum` on a **global level**, such that I can use that said `enum` in any file without having to import them.
Now, to my understand you can't do this with a `d.ts` file. I also saw other work arounds (e.g. this one https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14975 ) that don't seem best-practice but rather a "fix". Or questions, that aren't fully answered (e.g. [Enums in typescript d.ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62109542/enums-in-typescript-d-ts-file) )

Now, apparently a way to go is to create a `common.ts` and handle any `enum` in that file. How exactly do I have to proceed in order to make this possible:

**Some global.ts file**

```ts
 enum someEnum{
        first = 'someString',
        second = "someOtherString'
    }
```

**a.ts file**

```ts
//without any imports
const myFirstEnumValue = someEnum.first // resulting in "someString"
```

**Context**

I'm writing a React, Electron App and don't want to declare/define my `enums` twice, in `electron.ts` (sometimes called `main`) and in any react file. This works without any issue with `types` and `interfaces` in a file called `types.d.ts` (filepath is added to `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json`) but again, not with `enums`

Comment: After thinking about this for a few minutes, this seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Mmh I was hoping there's a easy way around this because importing enums over and over again seems tidious.

Comment: Does your editor not have auto-import features? Anyways, a [`const enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums) might do the trick. Const enums are different from regular enums in that they are basically a compiler trick. They get replaced with their constant value, unlike regular enums which stay as `MyEnum.EnumMember`.